# Chrome console.log contradictions

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have a simple class

```
function TrueNinja() {
   this.vanish = function() { return this; };
}
```

creating a new object from this

```
var someNinja = new TrueNinja();
```

when i do the following in chrome i get two different outputs

```
console.log(someNinja instanceof TrueNinja); // i get true
console.log("someNinja: " + someNinja instanceof TrueNinja); //i get false
```

WHY?? :-( the first statement is the correct output since someNinja IS an instance of TrueNinja... but why do i get false in the next statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give like this:

```
"someNinja: " + (someNinja instanceof TrueNinja);
```

The reason is, the whole `"someNinja: " + someNinja` is compared with `TrueNinja`.

So, this way, it compares, `"someNinja: " + someNinja` With the `TrueNinja`, where, the former is `string` and latter is `TrueNinja`. Hope it is clear! :)

The actual reason is because of Operator Precedence, where `+` comes before `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2):

That's due to operator precedence, `+` is evaluated before `instanceof`.